# Find the points of intersection of the line $x+16=7y$ and the circle $^2+^2−4+2=20$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find the 2 points of intersection of the line $+16=7$ and the circle $^2+^2−4+2=20$

The answer I read here is to solve for x and plug it in the cirlce equation. In the book and online, everyone get this answer when simplifying $(7−16)^2+^2−4(7−16)+2−20$ ⟹ $^2−5+6=0$

What I get after a first round of simplification is $50y^2-250y+300$ ⟹ $50(y^2-5y+16)=0$

The last step would be to use the quadratic equation to find the two points but why am I getting this extra coefficient 50 that the answer key does not get? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You divide both sides by $50$ to get $y^2 - 5y + 6 = 0$.

Comment: That is what I actually thought while writing my question, but it seemed almost too easy to be the answer... I guess it is. Thank you!

Comment: $50\ne 0$, therefore $y^2-5y+16=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You divide both sides by $50$ to get $y^2 - 5y + 6 = 0$. This step is valid because $50 \ne 0$, so both the LHS and the RHS have a defined value.